# Is the unit circle the only infinite compact subgroup of the multiplicative group of non-zero complex numbers?

Tags: group-theory, analysis, compactness, infinite-groups

Let $G$ be an infinite subgroup of $(\mathbb C \setminus \{0\},.)$ such that $G$ is compact as a subset of $\mathbb C$ , then is it true that $G=S^1$ ?

I know that $G \subseteq S^1$ ; and since any closed subset of $S^1$ is compact in complex plane , so basically I am asking whether any infinite subgroup of $S^1$ which is closed in the complex plane , must necessarily be $S^1$ .

Answer (score 10):

Table of contents:

1. A sketchy outline considering cases of whether or not $G$ contains a nonroot of unity.
2. An elaboration on the claim about what happens if $G$ contains a nonroot of unity.
3. An alternative approach not depending on whether or not $G$ contains a nonroot of unity.

---

1.

If $a\in G$ is not a root of unity, then $\{a^n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is dense in $S^1$.  Since $G$ is closed, this implies $G=S^1$.

On the other hand, if every $a\in G$ is a root of unity, and $G$ is infinite, then the set of $n$ such that $G$ has a primitive $n$th root of unity is infinite, and the union of the sets of all powers of such roots is dense, containing $n$ equally spaced points on the circle for arbitrarily large $n$.  Again, density and closedness implies $G=S^1$.

---

2.

Elaboration on the first claim:

Suppose $a\in G$ is not a root of unity.  Take $a=e^{i\theta}$ with $0<|\theta|<\pi$.  Taking powers of $a$, let $k\in \mathbb N$ be the smallest exponent greater than $1$ such that $a^k$ passes $1\in S^1$, going counterclockwise if $\theta>0$, otherwise clockwise. Then either $a^k$ or $a^{k-1}$ has less than half the arclength to $1$ as $a$, that is, we can write it as $a_2=e^{i\theta_2}$ with $0<|\theta_2|<\dfrac{|\theta|}{2}$.   Continuing this with $a_2\in G$ (also not a root of unity), we get an $a_3$, a power of $a_2$, such that $a_3=e^{i\theta_3}$ and $0<|\theta_3|<\dfrac{|\theta_2|}{2}$. Continuing indefinitely we get a sequence $a_1=a, a_2,a_3,\ldots$ of powers of $a$ getting arbitrarily close (but not equal) to $1$.  If $|a_n-1|<\varepsilon$, then powers of $a_n$ cover $S^1$ with consecutive points with distance less than $\varepsilon$.

---

3.

Because $G$ is infinite and $S^1$ is compact, $G$ has an accumulation point, and thus $G$ contains unequal but arbitrarily close elements.  For all $\varepsilon>0$, there exist $a,b\in G$ such that $0<|a-b|<\varepsilon$.  Then $c=ab^{-1}$ is in $G$ and $0<|c-1|<\varepsilon$.  Consecutive powers of $c$ cover the circle with points less than $\varepsilon$ apart.  Hence $G$ is dense, and assuming it is closed, it must be $S^1$.

---

3.b.

Elaborating by request on showing that density follows from the above:

To show that $G$ is dense in $S^1$ is equivalent to showing that for all $x\in S^1$, for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $g\in G$ such that $|x-g|<\varepsilon$.  So, given such $x$ and $\varepsilon$, let $c=c(\varepsilon)$ be as above.  Either $x$ is a power of $c$ or there are consecutive powers $c^n$ and $c^{n+1}$ with $x$ lying between them, hence $|x-c^n|<|c^{n+1}-c^n|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: why is $ \{a^n : n\in \mathbb N\}$ dense in $S^1$ if $a$ is not a root of unity ?

Comment: $a=e^{i\theta}$ with $\theta>0$ such that for all $k$ and $m$ in $\mathbb N$, $k\theta\neq m\cdot 2\pi$, or in other words $\dfrac{2\pi}{\theta}$ is irrational. (Sorry this thought is unfinished I have to go.)

Comment: @SaunDev: I added elaboration, with a method not based (explicitly) on my previous comment.

Comment: I don't understand in the $3$rd para what  you do with $c$ ? Are you claiming $\{c^n : n \in \mathbb Z\}$ is dense in $S^1$ , or are you claiming that for every $\epsilon >0$ we get $c_{\epsilon} \in G$ such that $0<|c_{\epsilon}-1|<\epsilon $ and then $\cup_{\epsilon >0} \{c_{\epsilon} ^n : n\in \mathbb Z\}$ is dense in $S^1$ ? And in any case could you please provide an argument for the density part ? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @SaunDev: I wouldn't claim that $\{c^n\}$ is dense, because it would be false if $c$ is a root of unity.  It is the case that the union you indicated is dense. I will add elaboration on that.

Comment: Thought so ... thanks .. looking forward for the elaboration

Comment: This might be stupid .. why being not a power of $c$ ensures $x$ lies between some $c^n$ and $c^{n+1}$ ? If $c$ is a root of unity then I can see $x$ lies between two powers of $c$ , but why "consecutive " ? And I can't totally see it if $c$ is a non-root of unity (one more thing ...$c$ does not depend on $x$ right ? )

Comment: If this isn't sufficiently rigorous let me know, but it is because $c=e^{i\theta}$ and $c^n=e^{i n\theta}$, implying that powers of $c$ are always rotating in the same direction, eventually, by the Archimedian property of $\mathbb R$, wrapping all of the way around past $c$ again.  $x$ is somewhere in the circle, so in this process it will get passed. Look at a time when it gets passed, with $c^n$ just before, $c^{n+1}$ just after.  (This is independent of whether $c$ is a root of unity.)  Right, $c$ does not depend on $x$, because its powers are spread uniformly throughout the circle.

Comment: ah I see .. so because there is a positive integer $n$ with $n \theta > 2\pi$ so we can cover the circle  at laest full once

Comment: I can perceive that if $x$ lies between $c^n$  and $c^{n+1}$ then $|x-c^n| \le |c^{n+1}-c^n|$ , but I am stuck proving it rigorously , could you please help me out here ?

Comment: Arrange so that $c=e^{i \theta}$ with $|\theta|<\pi$, so that when we say $x$ lies between $c^n$ and $c^{n+1}$ it means we have an arc from $c^n$ to $c^{n+1}$ of arclength $|\theta|<\pi$, with $x$ on the interior of the arc.  The points $c^n$, $c^{n+1}$, $x$ form a triangle, with the angle at $x$ being obtuse, hence the side opposite $x$ has the (strictly) largest side length $|c^n-c^{n+1}|$.  I'm thinking making the geometric claims rigorous could be done with Thales's theorem and the Law of Cosines.

Comment: Or, rotate the picture to have the equivalent problem: If $0<\varphi<\theta<\pi$, then $|1-e^{i \varphi}|<|1-e^{i \theta}|$ which can be shown using trigonometry and/or calculus.  Or, instead of using $|z|$ use the arclength distance in the circle to have less to show (as it yields the same topology).

Answer (score 5):

Consider the continuous surjective homomorphism $f: \mathbb R \to S^1$ as $f(x)=e^{2\pi i x} , \forall x \in \mathbb R$ .

Then for any subgroup $H$ of $S^1$ , $f(f^{-1}(H))=H$ , where $f^{-1}(H)$ is a subgroup (as $f$ is a group homomorphism) of $(\mathbb R,+)$ . So , $f^{-1}(H)$ is either cyclic or dense in $\mathbb R$ . If $f^{-1}(H)$ is dense , then $f$ being a continuous surjection , $f(f^{-1}(H))$ is dense , i.e. $H$ is dense in $S^1$ . Otherwise , $f^{-1}(H)$ is cyclic i.e. $f^{-1}(H)=b\mathbb Z$ for some $b \in \mathbb R$ . Two cases appear .

CASE I : $ b \in \mathbb Q$ : Say $b=p/q$ , where $p \in \mathbb Z , q\in \mathbb N$ . Then for any $n \in \mathbb Z$ , $n=kq+r ; 0\le r<q$ ,

then $e^{2\pi i bn}=e^{2\pi i(p/q)(kq+r)}=e^{2\pi i r/q } ; 0\le r<q$ . So then

$H=f(f^{-1}(H))=f(b\mathbb Z)=\{e^{2\pi i bn}:n\in \mathbb Z\} \subseteq \{e^{2\pi i r/q } : 0\le r <q\} $ , hnece $H$ is finite .

CASE II : $b$ is irrational

Then $\mathbb Z+b\mathbb Z$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ and noticing $\mathbb Z \subseteq ker f$ (actually it is equal , but we don't need that ) , we get

$H=f(f^{-1}(H))=f(b\mathbb Z)=f(\mathbb Z+b\mathbb Z)$ , and since $f$ is continuous surjection , so $H=f(\mathbb Z+b \mathbb Z)$ is dense in $S^1$ .

So we see that any subgroup of $S^1$ is either finite or dense in $S^1$ , hence if it is closed and infinite , it should be whole of $S^1$ .

Answer (score 0):

Since $G$ is infinite and $S^1=S$ is compact, there is a sequence of distinct points $(z_n)$ in $G$ that converges to some $z\in S.$ Because $G$ is compact, $z\in G.$ The sequence $z_nz^{-1}$ is then a sequence of distinct points in $G$ converging to $1.$ Thus given any neighborhood $U$ of $1,$ there is a point of $G$ in $U\setminus \{1\}.$

Let $\epsilon > 0.$ From the above it follows that there exists $w\in G$ such that $w=e^{it}$ for some $t\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon), t\ne 0.$ Let $N>2\pi/\epsilon$ be an integer. Define $A = \{w,w^2,\dots, w^N\}.$ Then $A\subset G,$ and every point in $S$ lies within $\epsilon$ of some point of $A$ (measuring distance in arc length).

Now a subset $D$ of $S$ is dense in $S$ iff given $\epsilon>0$ and a point $z\in S,$ there exists $w\in D$ within $\epsilon$ of $z.$ We have shown $G$ has this property. Thus $G$ is dense in $S,$ i.e., $\overline G = S.$ Because $G$ is compact, $G =\overline G,$ hence $G=S.$

Answer (score 0):

Using the topological isomorphism $S^1 \cong \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ and lifting the situation to $\mathbb{R}$, you are asking that, if $\tilde{G}$ is a subgroup which intersects $[0,1]$ infinitely, then is $\tilde{G}$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

The answer is yes, since for such $\tilde{G}$, one can always find elements $g\in \tilde{G}$  with arbitrary small absolute value and then by looking at the subgroup $g\mathbb{Z} \subset \tilde{G}$, one can conclude that $\tilde{G}$ is indeed dense in $\mathbb{R}$; it follows that $G$ is dense in $S^1$ too.